# Oscilloscope noise detection from VFD ~50V peak to peak

Tags: oscilloscope

When I connect one lead of an oscilloscope to the frame of a machine (grounded) I see a +25 to -25V DC spike happening at about 12kHz. I suspect this is being generated by a bad ground either in the motor or vfd. I leave the other lead not connected, just hanging in the air.

What am I measuring when I connect one lead to the frame and leave another just hanging in the air?

Answer (score 1):

The ground of most oscilloscopes is directly connected to the ground pin on the AC power cord.

The signal you see could be from the equipment you are testing, or it could be on the ground of the oscilloscope.

The oscilloscope is showing the voltage difference between the probe and the AC ground.

Comment: Is the ground wire on the 110 cord powering the oscilloscope connected to the 0V reference of the oscilloscope? Is this acting as an antenna?

Comment: Yes, the 110 ground is connected to the 0v ref.  It is probably not acting as an an antenna but the ground may have have a different voltage than the ground of the equipment.

Answer (score 1):

You're not measuring anything, you're just displaying crap if your probe's ground connection is floating.

Answer (score 0):

Your measuring rf noise. Most likely radiated from the VFD. You always need some ground reference.